# Use asymptotic equality to solve limit of difference of functions

Tags: real-analysis, limits, asymptotics, radicals

I have to compute the following limit
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to+\infty}\sqrt{x^2+1}-\sqrt{x^2+x}$$
I have rewritten the function $f(x)$ as
$$f(x)=\frac{x^2+1-x^2-x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+\sqrt{x^2+x}}=-\frac{1}{2}$$

Now since $\sqrt{x^2+1}\sim x$ and $\sqrt{x^2+x}\sim x$, as $x\to\infty$, if I consider these asymptotic equalities I could write:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}x-x=0$$
but in such a way the result is wrong...What is wrong in the second idea of resolution?

Comment: It's wrong, because you can't change the functions like that. We also have $x+1\sim x$ as $x\to\infty$, but surely $(x+1)-x$ does not tend to $0$.

Comment: you have to consider higher terms

Comment: @SineoftheTime do you mean the Taylor expansion?

Comment: yes, higher terms in the expansion

Comment: @jin I've added an answer, tell me if it's clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first method is fine, but if you want to use asymptotic expansion, you have to consider higher terms. Recall that $(1+t)^a\sim1+at$ as $t\to 0$:
$$\sqrt{x^2+1}-\sqrt{x^2+x}=x\left(\sqrt{1+\frac1{x^2}}-\sqrt{1+\frac1{x}}\right)\sim x\left(1+\frac1{2x^2}-1-\frac1{2x}\right)\to-\frac12 $$